# Using flex-basis instead of width/height causes siblings to not expand

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have three `div`s arranged horizontally in a row flexbox, which is itself contained in a row flexbox (let's say, for a footer component):

```
<div id="footer-container" class="flex-row">
  (other components that are irrelevant for this example)
  <div id="row" class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <span>Here is a link</span>
      <span>Here is another link</span>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 48px;"></div>
    <div class="flex-col">
      <span>Yet another link</span>
      <span>And another link</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/omp2xLuw/
[image: working example with width]

This is a simplified example of the use case in my code, which is creating a reusable `<Row>` React component and works as expected (a 48px spacer between the two text `div`s). As part of that, I want the client code to be able to use a CSS media query to change the  to a column flex-box at an arbitrary breakpoint. Therefore, the spacer will have to also change from `width` to `height` when this occurs. It would be nice if the client could simply override `flex-direction`, and the spacer automatically changes axis to match the new direction.

I tried to solve this by using `flex-basis` on the spacer instead of `width`/`height`:

```
<div id="footer-container" class="flex-row">
  (other components that are irrelevant for this example)
  <div id="row" class="flex-row">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <span>Here is a link</span>
      <span>Here is another link</span>
    </div>
    <div style="flex-basis: 48px; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div>
    <div class="flex-col">
      <span>Yet another link</span>
      <span>And another link</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fmdvp52z/
[image]
But it causes the text to wrap instead of expanding width to fit on one line. My understanding is that `flex-basis` is supposed to act like `width` or `height` depending on the direction of the flexbox, so why is this happening? Is this a browser bug?

Comment: read the "browser bugs" section of the accepted answer in the duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for the link; I had already read that post beforehand but I see now that this behavior exists across Chrome/Firefox/Safari, which leads me to think that it isn't an isolated bug and likely a subtlety that I'd like to learn about